# Youtube Video Upload on web with Google API and scope youtube.upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth

I am trying to upload a video on Youtube developed in MVC but  its failing with below error for Web Application while it works fine for Local system.
Server Hosted on AWS.

> Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=abcd&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.upload%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive" for authorization. See inner exception for details.

Seeking help

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using the Google APIs .net client library.   There are several types of clients with Google login Web client and Native application client.

The code used to authenticate the two applications is different.   When you authcate with a native client you spawn the web browser on the local pc.   With a web application hosted on a website the browser must be opened on the users client machine.

THe error you are seeing here is normally becouse you are hosting this and its trying to open the web browser on the server itself rather than the users clinet.
You should follow this tutorial [web-applications-aspnet-mvc](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

Add your own implementation of FlowMetadata.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

FlowMetadata is an abstract class that contains your own logic for retrieving the user identifier and the IAuthorizationCodeFlow you are using.

In the above sample code a new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow is created with the right scopes, client secrets, and the data store. Consider adding your own implementation of IDataStore, for example you could write one that uses EntityFramework.

Implement your own controller that uses a Google API service. The following sample uses a DriveService:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Services;

using Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public async Task IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                        ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
                    });

                // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE..
                // SAMPLE CODE:
                var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
                ViewBag.Message = "FILE COUNT IS: " + list.Items.Count();
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implement your own callback controller. The implementation should be something like this:

```
using Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers
{
    public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
    {
        protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
        {
            get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to alter the sample from google drive to Youtube.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, we will work on your suggestion. However so far, we tried below code and its working on localhost and not on Web Server, can you please check. : UserCredential credential =  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId =< "Our client ID">, ClientSecret = <"Our Client secret"> } , scopes  , "user"  , CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")).Result;